# AttributeError: object has no attribute 'user_agent'

Tags: python, oop, web-scraping, inheritance, twitter

I'm writing a tweepy bot using the Twitter API, specifically the Twitter API v2. The script is supposed to stream some tweets using a code word and write them to a file. I'm trying to add a `filename` parameter to the constructor of the `StdOutListener` class.

```
import tweepy
import credentials

class StdOutListener(tweepy.StreamingClient):

    def __init__(self, bearer_token, filename):
        self.bearer_token = bearer_token
        self.filename = filename

    def on_data(self, data):
        with open(self.filename) as file:
            file.write(data)
        print("[+] File written!")
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    filename = "tweets.json"
    listener = StdOutListener(credentials.BEARER_TOKEN, filename)
    listener.add_rules(tweepy.StreamRule("Boston Celtics"))
    listener.filter()
```

However, whenever I run this I get the error: `AttributeError: 'StdOutListener' object has no attribute 'user_agent'`. I think it has something to do with a inheritance. So I've tried using `super` but to no avail. I've searched on StackOverflow to find an answer to this problem, but haven't found one. What's causing the AttributeError?

Comment: What exactly did you try with `super`? If `StreamingClient` supplies the `user_agent` attribute, you need something like `super().__init__()` in `StdOutListener.__init__`. Otherwise, you're going to have to explain where you think `user_agent` should come from, if you don't create it yourself.

Comment: @chepner The ```user_agent``` attribute is from the parent class ```tweepy.StreamingClient```.

Comment: And it's not set because you never call `StreamingClient.__init__`.

Answer (score 0):

Just had this issue trying to pass a parameter to that class.
You need to super().**init**(bearer_token)

```
class StdOutListener(tweepy.StreamingClient):
    def __init__(self, bearer_token, filename):
        super().__init__(bearer_token)
        self.filename = filename
```